# Printing Vaules in a pattern using multi-threading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

The goal is to print:
Fibonacci No.:
Square of Fibo:
Prime No:
Square of the Prime Number:
in a pattern upto first 10 vaules using multi threading .
Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time

def FibonacciNumbers(n):
    f1 = 0
    f2 = 1
    if (n < 1):
        return
    for x in range(0, n):
        print("Fibonacci No.: ")
        print(f2)
        time.sleep(1)
        next = f1 + f2
        f1 = f2
        f2 = next

def FibonacciSq(n):
    f1 = 0
    f2 = 1
    if (n < 1):
        return
    for x in range(0, n):
        print("Square of Fibo: ")
        print(f2*f2)
        time.sleep(1)
        next = f1 + f2
        f1 = f2
        f2 = next

def prime(x):
    i=1
    counter = 0
    while True:
        c=0;
        for j in range (1, (i+1), 1):
            a = i%j
            if (a==0):
                c = c+1
        if (c==2):
            print("Prime No: ")
            print (i)
            time.sleep(1)
            counter = counter + 1
            if counter >= x:
                break
        i=i+1

def primeSq(x):
    i=1
    counter = 0
    while True:
        c=0;
        for j in range (1, (i+1), 1):
            a = i%j
            if (a==0):
                c = c+1
        if (c==2):
            print("Square of the Prime Number: ")
            print (i*i)
            time.sleep(1)
            counter = counter + 1
            if counter >= x:
                break
        i=i+1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=FibonacciNumbers, args=(10,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=FibonacciSq, args=(10,))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=prime, args=(10,))
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=primeSq, args=(10,))
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    # t1.join()

    t2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    # t2.join()

    t3.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    # t3.join()

    t4.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    # t4.join()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()

    print("Done!")
```

The out put I got from it is:

The output is generated in a random manner.
I think it is due to some collision in the time when the result is generating .
Can't figure out how to pause one thread until the next is finshed.
Please help me to fix the output.

```
Fibonacci No.:
1
Fibonacci No.:
1
Square of Fibo:
1
Fibonacci No.:
2
Square of Fibo:
1
Prime No:
2
34
Square of Fibo:
169
441
Prime No:
Square of the Prime Number:
289
Fibonacci No.:
19
55
Square of Fibo:
1156
Square of Fibo:
Square of the Prime Number:
361
3025
Prime No:
23
Square of the Prime Number:
529
Prime No:
29
Square of the Prime Number:
841
Done!
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to use threads if you don’t want the code to run concurrently?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I want to get the output. If you are talking about the sleep. I used that to get the output only.

Comment: That isn’t what I’m talking about. Remove the threading stuff. Call the functions directly. You’ll get the same output, just in proper order.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The task I got is to use make it work using threading. If you can guide me where to modify that would be great help. I  mustn't remove threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple threads concurrently access a single resource (in this case: the standard output), you need to somehow synchronise access (meaning: make all except one thread wait until the resource is free to use again).

There are several solutions for this depending on the exact use-case. The most general solution is to use a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects). This requires two changes:

1. Declare a global lock at the start of your file:

   ```
   lock = threading.Lock()
   ```
2. Inside each function, wrap both `print` statements inside a locked block, e.g.:

   ```
   with lock:
       print("Fibonacci No.: ")
       print(f2)
   ```

Note that locking in this fashion is quite an inefficient operation! If the aim of using concurrency was performance, this solution might well completely defeat the purpose. Writing efficient multi-threaded code is rarely trivial, and efficient synchronisation in particular requires a lot of though. (There are added complications because the most common Python’s implementations use a [global interpreter lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), which implies that execution for the most part doesn’t *really* happen in parallel anyway.)

The easiest practical, efficient solution in most cases is to *avoid sharing resources* between threads. In your case, this would mean not writing any output (functions that write output are generally suspect anyway): let each function generate results and collect them inside a list, or `yield` them as a generator. Then you can generate results in parallel, and print them sequentially *afterwards* (doing so requires a change though, since `threading` does not easily support functions that return values; however, the module `concurrent.futures` does).

Comment: This is good! But using lock doesn't give the desired output though. But I get your point.